# simplepie get_permalink won't returne whole href

Tags: php

This works fine and returns the item permalink

```
$item->get_permalink()
```

But if I want to return the whole url the code below will return the feed url instead of the item permalink.

What is wrong with this code below? Why it doesn't return the whole href?

```
$link ='<a href=".$item->get_permalink()."></a>';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$link ="<a href=\"$item->get_permalink()\"></a>";
```

or

```
$link ='<a href="'.$item->get_permalink().'"></a>';
```

instead of

```
$link ='<a href=".$item->get_permalink()."></a>';
```

Comment: i tested it works for me. .. can you show your get_permalink() function

Comment: it's built in wp or not?

Comment: I am not sure about wp but according to rule it should work

Comment: use again `$link ='<a href="'.$item->get_permalink().'"></a>';` this